# Ringtone de notificação padrão do aparelho

Tags: android

No meu aplicativo tenho nas configurações uma opção para que o usuário selecione o som que será executado ao receber notificação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu abro um `AlertDialog` e list o toque padrão do próprio aparelho:

```
Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, defaultRingtoneUri);
```

Obtenho o título e o local com:

```
//Titulo
defaultRingtone.getTitle(context)
// Path
defaultRingtoneUri.getPath()
```

E as outras notificações, obtidas assim:

```
RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(context);
manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();
```

O título e o local, após fazer o *loop*, obtenho com:

```
// Título
cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)
// Path
cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX) + "/" + cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX)
```

## Problema

O que acontece é que o primeiro nome da notificação (que eu obtenho pelo primeiro código), no meu aparelho o título mostra **Toque padrão (Tejat)**, o que é verdade, porém quando eu vou tocar o som é um diferente e não o **Tejat**.

E quando toco o **Tejat** obtido pelo `RigntoneManager`, é o som correto.

> **Toque padrão (Tejat)**: /system/notification_sound 
> **Tejat**:
>   content://media/internal/audio/media/7

## Pergunta

O que acontece para que o toque padrão não seja realmente o correto? Como resolver isso?